# cannot import name python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, import, module

Hi I have created a main page with python with the code of:

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Second file with the code of:

```
from flask import Flask
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_kEY'] = 'computer1'
    return app
```

I have enter from website import 'create app' and I am getting an error message which states
cannot import name 'createapp'
python\python 310\lib\site.package\website__init__py
When I press run the above comes up. Can someone please advise?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have made a init page and a main paid and when enter from website site import create_app which is on the from flask import Flask on the __init__ page when I try to run. The error message 'cannot import name 'create_app python\python3.10\lib\site.package\website__init__py.